# Rspec error Wrong Number of Arguments 0 for 1 on Update test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have no idea why this is happening. Googling didn't help. Can you? Thanks!

```
1) AuctionsController#update displays a flash message on success
 Failure/Error: patch :update, id: @auction, auction: {title: 'New title'}
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

## test

```
describe "#update" do
before do
  @auction = Auction.create!(title: 'Testing3', details: 'Some description', reserve: 500, deadline: Time.now + 1.days)
  patch :update, id: @auction, auction: {title: 'New title'}
  @auction.reload

end

it "displays a flash message on success" do
  expect(flash[:success]).to be
  # expect(response).to redirect_to(@auction)
end
end
```

Comment: If you run rspec with the `-b` option you should get more backtrace which could be informative

Comment: It looks like the problem lies in your update method on AuctionsController. Maybe post the code for that method and/or use the -b flag mentioned and post more of the stack trace.

Comment: def update
    @auction = Auction.find params[:id]
    @auction.update!
end

Comment: You should update your question to include the code you just included in the comment, not only because the information is required to answer your question, but because you can't format the code properly in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in your `update` method. The `update!` method requires an argument and you haven't provided one, hence the `0 for 1` error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

```
def update
  @auction = Auction.find params[:id]
  @auction.update!
end
```

This update is the issue, it needs an argument but you haven't given it any, the correct line would be

```
@auction.update! params[:auction]
```

Or even better if you have your strong params method set correctly

```
@auction.update! auction_params
```